# Android Geolocation Google Maps Crashing On Start Up

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-location

I posted my code below my application shows no errors int eh debug menu, when I run it logcat shows one error I posted it below. When I try to run the app on my phone it closes and stops responding and im not sure why. I was following an online tutorial and did it exactly how it said. Please help.

```
10-07 14:50:02.901: I/Process(11653): Sending signal. PID: 11653 SIG: 9
10-07 14:50:06.124: W/dalvikvm(11801): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1346 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
10-07 14:50:06.124: D/dalvikvm(11801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
10-07 14:50:06.134: D/AndroidRuntime(11801): Shutting down VM
10-07 14:50:06.134: W/dalvikvm(11801): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4129bac8)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:284)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at com.example.gloc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-07 14:50:06.134: E/AndroidRuntime(11801):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

MainActivity.java


package com.example.gloc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            //Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            //dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

Layout

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>

Manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gloc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 <permission
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
             android:value="IEARASEDTHSITOHIDEIT"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gloc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the map options in onCreate, as it has not yet been instantiated.  Try doing all of the stuff in OnLocationChanged to your GoogleMap object in onResume() instead of onCreate().